# NodeJS AWS DynamoDB V3 How to refresh assumed role permissions

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, refresh, credentials

we managed to assume a role, but it does not automatically refresh access, so after some time we get a timeout err.

We found not proper documentation on how to refresh credentials, so I was wondering if someone could provide a code example of how to setup this up properly.

We already tried with `credentialDefaultProvider({ assumeRole })` in the DynamoDBClient constructor options, but it doesn't even call it.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Secure Token Service is your friend for assuming a role and use its credentials.

```
// this example uses Typescript
import { AssumeRoleCommand, Credentials, STSClient } from '@aws-sdk/client-sts'


// get / refresh Credentials
const stsClient = new STSClient({ region: <YOUR_REGION> })

const data = await stsClient.send(
    new AssumeRoleCommand({
        RoleArn: <ROLE_ARN>,
        RoleSessionName: <SOME_SESSION_NAME>,
        DurationSeconds: <DURATION_IN_SECONDS>
    }),
)
// now use the Credentials
// data.Credentials
```

You can also check if the Credentials are still valid before your requests:

```
if(new Date() > new Date(data.Expiration)){
    // refresh Credentials 
}
```

Useful links:

- [AWS Secure Token Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/welcome.html)
- [AWS STS Example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/example_sts_AssumeRole_section.html)

Comment: i asked explicitly for how to refresh credentials, but that is the only part you didn't touch upon. -_-

Comment: you refresh the Credentials by sending the `new AssumeRoleCommand` like described in the answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).